# Asymptotic Expansion of a easy function

Tags: complex-analysis

It is possible to get a Asymptotic Expansion around the infinity of the function
$$x^{-z}$$ when z tend to infinity
Thanks

Comment: What is $ x$ here?

Comment: x is any number  z is the variable

Comment: Asymptotic in which sense? The function has an essential singularity at $\infty$.

Comment: somethig like this $$\text{Normal}\left[\text{Series}\left[x^{-z},\{z,\infty ,3\}\right]\right]$$

Comment: You should write it like this: $a^{-x}$, this is easier to understand for it is using accepted conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Let us change $\;x\;$ for $\;a\;,\;\;a\neq 0$ , in order to avoid confusion. Choose now any branch for the complex logarithm, and look at $\;a^{1/z}\;$ around $\;z=0\;$:

$$a^{-1/z}=e^{-\frac1z\log a}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\log^na}{n!z^n}$$

and we get an essential singularity.

Comment: anyway Timbuc your answer it is not  correct so that $$(N=0.933032)\left(-\frac{\log ^3(x)}{6 z^3}+\frac{\log ^2(x)}{2 z^2}-\frac{\log (x)}{z}+1\text{/.}\, x\to 2\text{/.}\, z\to 10\right)$$ and $$(N=0.000976563)\left(x^{-z}\text{/.}\, x\to 2\text{/.}\, z\to 10\right)$$ thns anyway to try

Comment: @antonioasis Well, perhaps I made a mistake, of course...but I can't see where, and I've no idea what you tried to show with those calculations you wrote, with those little arrows, those strange symbols $\;1/.x\,,\,\,2/.z \;\;??\;$ ,  and etc. Anyway, are you claiming that is **not** an essential singularity, or what?